# How to protect/store an object server side with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, client-server

I'm working with AngularJS and NodeJS on a web application where the user has to find a correct answer between randomly generated questions.
I don't know how to "protect" the answer from the client.

The questions/answers are generated in objects like that:

```
var question = {
  answer: 'A',
  choices: ['A', 'B']
};
```

In this example, the user has to choose between *A* and *B* and the correct answer is *A*.

I'd like to do something like that:

1. The client ask the server for a new question
2. The server loads the question/answer and returns the *choices* only to the client
3. The client sends an answer to the server
4. The server compare the answer sent by the client to his *answer* and returns the result to the client (i. e. correct or wrong)

Since the questions/answers are randomly generated, the answer needs to be defined by the server after the step 1.

I was thinking about something like:

```
var answer = 0;

app.get('/generateQuestion', function (req, res) {
    var question = getQuestion();
    answer = question.answer
    res.send(question.choices);
});

app.post('/answer', function (req, res) {
    if (req.answer === answer) {
        res.send('Correct');
    } else {
        res.send('Wrong');
    }
});
```

But this stored answer will be shared between users causing conflicts...

I'd like to avoid sending the answer to the client when the question is asked, but I don't know how to "store" it on server side.

How would you handle it? How can I secure a bit this questions/answers?

Comment: This is really a far too general a question, but typically you'd send the possible answers to the browser along with a unique id that would be used to request the actual answer from the server. The usual way to do this would be to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) for browser to server requests (that did not require a page refresh) and some database at your server that would allow you to store questions, possible answers, and the actual answer indexed by a unique id.

Comment: @RobRaisch Thanks Rob. I didn't mention it but I can't store the questions/answer in a database (it would be easier...). I just randomly generate them from a 3rd-party API. I don't want to store them since they will be used only once. But may be I should store them temporally in JSON files then delete after the "quiz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment, so I have to post this as an answer, but I would store the questions/ answers in the user's session using something like express-session which will automatically store the data in the database you set it up with. You could do this by storing question/ answer pairs in an array, and then sending the question and it's index in the array to the client. They can then send the answer and the index in the array, and you can check if the answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam. As I mentioned in my comment to Rob, I don't want to store the QA in a database. They're temporary and always changing. Do you think a shared array between users is a good idea? I can remove the QA from the array once the user answer (or after a certain amount of time). I was also thinking about temporary files per users. What do you think about it?

Comment: Hi yes, you could store them in a a shared array but i don't think it's best practise. You mentioned you don't want to store them in a database but then suggested above about storing them in temporay JSON files and delete after the quiz? A NoSQL database would perform exactly this function and would be a more standard appraoch. express-sessions even hides the whole database accessing/ saving from the code and you would just access like a normal variable.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider encoding the question, options to choose from, and the correct answer in the browser-side JavaScript in such a way as to hide them from casual viewing.

*Note this **would not** completely protect the answer from anyone but unsophisticated users, but it would give you some modicum of privacy.*

Here's the solution I propose (See it live at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8x2o27rr/)):

```
<div>Q:&nbsp;<span id="q"></span></div>
<div>1:&nbsp;<span id="o1"></span></div>
<div>2:&nbsp;<span id="o2"></span></div>
<div>3:&nbsp;<span id="o3"></span></div>
<div>Placeholder:&nbsp;<span id='p'></span></div>
<div>A:&nbsp;<span id='a'></span></div>

<script>
  var cc=''.charCodeAt,sh=[].shift,jo=[].join,sp=''.split,
      ma=[].map,fc=String.fromCharCode,lo=''.toLowerCase,
      fe=[].forEach,
      /* #1 */ r=function(s){
        var f=function(c){
          var v=cc.call(lo.call(c)),t=v>=96,k=(v-96+12)%26+1;
          if(v<97 || v>122) return c; return fc(k+(t?96:64));
        };
        return jo.call(ma.call(sp.call(s,''),f), '');
      },
      /* #2 */ d=[
        'Gur dhrfgvba gb nfx?',   // The question to ask?
        'Svefg cbffvoyr nafjre',  // First possible answer
        'Frpbaq cbffvoyr nafjre', // Second possible answer
        'Guveq cbffvoyr nafjre',  // Third possible answer
        '[Naq gur nafjre vf...]', // [And the answer is...]
        'Gur npghny nafjre!',     // The actual answer!
      ],
      /* #3 */ t=['q','o1','o2','o3','p','a'];

  /* #4 */ fe.call(t,function(tr){
    document.getElementById(tr).innerText=r(sh.call(d));
  });
</script>
```

Where

- #1: `r` is an obfuscated implementation of the [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) variation of the [Caesar Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)
- #2: `d` is an array of ROT13 encoded strings which should be replaced each time a new question is presented to the user
- #3: `t` is an array of DOM element ids to identify into which elements to insert the decoded strings
- #4: inserts the decoded strings into their appropriate elements.

When each new question is retrieved from the server, the encoded values of the question, choices of answer, placeholder for the answer, and the actual answer itself are substituted for the values in `d`.

In your application, the options might be radio buttons with attached `onClick` event handlers which would check the clicked option against the decoded answer to determine success or failure.

Here is an un-obfuscated version of the ROT13 cipher:

```
var rot13 = function(s){
    return s.split('').map(function(c){
      var v=c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
      if(v<97 || v>122) return c;
      var t = v>=96,
          k = (v - 96 + 12) % 26 + 1;
      return String.fromCharCode(k + (t ? 96 : 64));
  }).join('');
};
```